# How to set default value to dropdown list using angularjs viewmodel

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set default value to drop down list using angularjs. I pasted the code below.
This is viewmodel code and html code:

```
    appmodule.factory("testpage1ViewModel", function() { 
      function Testpage1ViewModel () {
    this.SearchContainer1 = {
        cmbGender:''
    };
    this.message = '';

    this.SearchContainer1_Master_cmbGender = { 
        ValidValues: [ 
                    { id: '1', name: 'Male' },
                    { id: '2', name: 'Female' },
                    { id: '3', name: 'Transgender' }
        ],
        DefaultValue: { id: '1', name: 'Male' }

           };

     }
               return Testpage1ViewModel;
 });


 <select name="cmbGender" 
                            class="form-control"
                            ng-options="option.name for option in viewModel.SearchContainer1_Master_cmbGender.ValidValues track by option.id"
                            ng-model="viewModel.SearchContainer1.cmbGender"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-init. See example below:

In HTML

```
<select ng-change="fruitselect(fruitname)" ng-model="fruitname" ng-init="fruitname = fruits[0]" >

    <option ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" value="{{fruit}}">{{fruit}}</option>
   </select>
```

And in Controller,

```
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange','banana', 'grapes', 'plum'];
```

Comment: The list of values taken from the view model like above code. I am adding complete viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If your existing code is correct then you can define ng-model like this :

```
<select ng-model="DefaultValue.name" name="cmbGender" class="form-control" ng-options="option.name for option in viewModel.SearchContainer1_Master_cmbGender.ValidValues track by option.id"></select>
```

Comment: As i wrote that  *If your existing code is correct then you can define ng-model like this